# Searching Twitter feeds

Tags: twitter, arduino, processing

I'm looking to take information from [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) feeds such as removed posts. Is it possible to do this through some sort of string match search by looking for keywords, that is, "this post removed"?

This is for an [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) project.

Answer (score 1):

It should be. Twitter just turned off their old API, though, so as long as you're willing to get an API key, you should be fine (https://dev.twitter.com). Grab the data with loadBytes or loadStrings called on the API URL and then start walking through the data you got back (http://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.htm) -- which in the new API will be JSON. You can use a JSON library to turn that into an actual object, but frankly if you want to do text matching, which you do, then there's really no need for Object repacking.